# Does Mac OS X code signing work like code signing on iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, code-signing

If I sign my Mac OS X app using my self-signed certificate, I am still able to modify the binary after signing and the OS doesn't complain about anything and the app will work just fine. If I modify an iOS binary then the app simply will not load on the device.

If it's actually meant to work like this on OS X, are there any ways to securely and reliably ensure integrity like the iOS-style code signing check?

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, code signing check only kicks in if the application is marked for quarantine by the operating system, i.e if the application is downloaded from the internet using safari or may be mail application.

The best way to test this is to set the quarantine attribute using xattr, something like xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "0001;4fce45e4;Safari;E17715E0-DB01-4EA3-A102-FBE7C2C8587A|com.apple.Safari"

Hope this helps.